# SQL Right join returning blank rows

Tags: sql, join, db2, right-join

I am trying to join the below tables:

Table A:

```
Type1   Type2   ID  Object  Location
Sample  Dummy   1   X111    111222
Sample  Dummy   2   X333    333444
Sample  Dummy   2   X333    555666
Sample  Red     1   X222    666777
Test    Red     1   X222    666777
Test    Red     1   X222    666777
```

Table B:

```
Source  Type2   ID  Object  Logged
SR1     Dummy   1   X111    17
SR1     Dummy   2   X333    1
SR1     Red     1   X222    12
SR2     Dummy   1   X111    9
SR2     Dummy   2   X333    9
SR2     Red     1   X222    20
```

My SQL code:

```
SELECT B.Source, B.Type2, B.ID, B.Object, B.Logged, A.Location 
FROM A RIGHT JOIN B ON 
    A.Type1='Sample' AND 
    A.Type2=B.Type2 AND 
    A.ID=B.ID AND 
    A.Object=B.Object 
WHERE B.Source='SR2'
```

I am expecting the following results:

```
Source  Type2   ID  Object  Logged  Location
SR1     Dummy   1   X111    17      111222
SR1     Dummy   2   X333    1       333444
SR1     Dummy   2   X333    1       555666
SR1     Red     1   X222    12      666777
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
Source  Type2   ID  Object  Logged  Location
SR1     Dummy   1   X111    17      111222
SR1     Dummy   2   X333    1       -
SR1     Dummy   2   X333    1       -
SR1     Red     1   X222    12      666777
```

What's wrong with my code? Please help.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Your sample data doesn't have `type1`, so the code should return an error.

Comment: Assuming `'Sample'=B.Type1` is a typo and should reference `A.Type1`, the query as presented does what you're saying it should do. [Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/SXWUO82827).

Comment: My apologies. There was a typo in my code, I meant to reference Type1 in the A table. I am using db2.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=1dae87474e871726189c91970caecaad) link with your sample data returns different result. Run the same statement **as is**. Do you get the same result? If not, then what's your db2 version and platform?

Comment: I'm unable to find out the version and the platform. I made a mistake trying to use right join. I wrapped the tables as sub-queries and used left join on them. This gave me the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is much easier to follow.  The issue is the filtering on `b.Type1 = 'Sample'`.  From what I can tell, that is not needed:

```
SELECT B.Source, B.Type2, B.ID, B.Object, B.Logged, A.Location 
FROM B LEFT JOIN
     A 
     ON A.Type2 = B.Type2 AND 
        A.ID = B.ID AND 
        A.Object = B.Object 
WHERE B.Source = 'SR2';
```

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo. I meant to reference A.Type1. I'm using db2. I will give this a try and if needed, I will do more research.